# Trap focus with in popup modal only IOS voiceOver

Tags: html, ios, safari, modal-dialog, voiceover

I have clickable link on the parent component which will launch custom modal on top of it. I am having big big issue trapping focus with in the modal only on safari ios VoiceOver. On swiping focus is going behind the parent clickable link. How can i trap focus only on modal and completely disable parent component after modal popup.

My application is on Angular 5

Here is modal template

```
<div class="modal-backdrop modal-open fade in" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"></div>
<div class="modal fade in"  id="confirmModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal-title" data-keyboard="false"  (keydown.escape)="cancel()"  >
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" id="btnClose" class="fa fa-times close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (tap)="cancel()"  (keydown.spacebar)="cancel()" (click)="cancel($event)" (keydown.space)="cancel()" (keydown.enter)="cancel();" (keydown.tab)="onTab()" (keydown.shift.tab)="onShiftTab()" (keydown.escape)="cancel()" ></button>                 
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="btnDefault" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (tap)="cancel()"  (keydown.enter)="cancel()" (click)="cancel($event)" (keydown.spacebar)="cancel()"  (keydown.space)="cancel()" (keydown.tab)="onTab()" (keydown.shift.tab)="onShiftTab()" (keydown.escape)="cancel()" attr.aria-label="cancelbutton">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" id="btnPrimary" class="btn btn-primary"  (tap)="onOK()" (keydown.enter)="onOK()" (click)="onOK($event)" (keydown.spacebar)="cancel()" (keydown.space)="onOK()" (keydown.tab)="onTab()" (keydown.shift.tab)="onShiftTab()" (keydown.escape)="cancel()" attr.aria-label="buttonLabel">Confirm</button>
            </div>
        </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, you should organize your html as

```
<body>
  <div>
    <!-- your main page -->
  </div>
  <div style="visibility:hidden">
    <!-- your dialog -->
  </div>
</body>
```

So that the dialog is a "sibling" of the main page.  When your dialog is displayed, you can add `aria-hidden="true"` to the main page and that will completely "hide" the background page from screen readers.  VoiceOver won't let you swipe to get to the background page if it's hidden.

```
<body>
  <div aria-hidden="true">
    <!-- your main page -->
  </div>
  <div style="visibility:visible">
    <!-- your dialog -->
  </div>
</body>
```

**Note** the use of the CSS `visibility` attribute on the dialog.  See https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2018/06/the-current-state-of-modal-dialog-accessibility/ for more information on that.  Look for the "Additional Gotchas to watch out for" heading.

Also note that you still have to trap the keyboard focus in the dialog.  `aria-hidden` has no affect on the keyboard, it only communicates to the screen reader.  To do that, you can use the `inert` attribute **and** a polyfill.  See the aforementioned blog for information on that too.

Comment: using with voice over enabled, swipes will move focus to browser next/previous buttons. which are also not part of popup. While JS focus does not work with voice over enabled to move focus back to popup. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you’re talking about the browser controls such as share, bookmark, forward, and backward, then that’s correct behavior. You can also swipe to the address bar. You don’t want to prevent access to elements outside the webpage.

Comment: can we change this behavior?

Comment: No, and that’s a good thing. You should not prevent the user from getting to the address bar and other browser controls.