# is it possible to focus trap in modal popup when using talkback or voiceover?

Tags: focus, voiceover, talkback

i have page with iframe
in the iframe when i click the button, popup will appear
when talback or voiceover is enabled, is it possible to focus trap only in the popup ?
so is it possible to achieve that i will be not able to move outside of the popup using swipe gesture ?
by outside i mean, than i will be not able to reach address bar or any other part of site or browser.

i found this
https://medium.com/@islam.sayed8/trap-focus-inside-a-modal-aa5230326c1b
but thats not working on mobile

am i right that its not possible as talback/voiceover are system functions ?

thanks

Comment: https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/#modal-view and https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/en/mobile/ios/development/#focus-an-element may help you according to what I understood in your question. 

Comment: thanks, but i need this also for talkback for android, so i want to do this in javascript (if its possible), i guess its not possible.

Comment: Have you tried using [`inert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/inert) in addition to `tabindex="-1"`?

Comment: I just found a similar question. Apparently, setting `aria-hidden` on the topmost element outside the dialog solves the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53561764/trap-focus-with-in-popup-modal-only-ios-voiceover